# Analyzing a Gaussian Quadrature function

Tags: python, gaussian

Trying to have Python solve the equation f(x) = ((2pi)^(-1/2))*e^((-x^(2))/2) using a Gaussian Quadrature from x= -4 to 4.

Trying to figure out how to tell python to integrate with respect to the line that intersects the graph at x = -4 and 4.

No idea how to even begin solving this problem, no error codes yet.

Comment: Apparently the answer should be around 0.9999.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the scipy library. the scipy.integrate sub-package includes a [Gaussian Quadrature](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html#gaussian-quadrature) you could use.

```
from scipy import integrate
from numpy import exp,pi

f = lambda x: ((2*pi)**(-1/2))*exp(-0.5*x**2)
print(integrate.quadrature(f, -4.0, 4.0))
```